# How to use User-Defined table types in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure to insert a bunch of rows for what I have created a user defined table type.

```
        INSERT INTO MAP_Deg_Cyr (
                   MAP_Deg_CYr_Id,
               Degree_Programme_Id,
               Duration_mode,
               Start_Course_Year_ID,
               Final_Course_Year_ID,
               Min_Year,
               Max_Year,
               Special_Condition_Cyr_Id,                           
               Is_Active )

               SELECT
              row_number() over(order by MAP_Deg_CYr_Id), 
              Degree_Programme_Id,
              Duration_mode,
              Start_Course_Year_ID,
              Final_Course_Year_ID,
              Min_Year,
              Max_Year,
              Special_Condition_Cyr_Id,
              Is_Active FROM @mapTable
```

Here MAP_Deg_CYr_Id is a Max+1 column means the value for this column will be the max(MAP_Deg_CYr_Id)+1. I have problem how to generate max+1 value if I am getting the value from user defined table

Comment: Why don't you use Identity?

Comment: Any error can also make the identity increase. here the ID will be used for further relation and calculation and some more reasons are there.....